# Javascript - how to get a key by it's order in the data model

Tags: javascript

is it possible to get a key by it's order. I have a data model that has changing keys.

for example

```
{A: 1, k:2}
```

it will change at some point but the order will be the same.. For example

```
{J: 1, F:2}
```

Is there a way to to get the properties by it's order (first, second)??

Comment: Object properties are unordered.

Comment: There is no "first" and "second". The property names are all you've got. You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of property names, but there's no rule that says what order you'll get them in.

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary has no order, so what you can do is convert it to an array of pairs, sort it and then iterate over it.

```
var arr = {A:300, B:60, C:200}
var sortable = [];
for (var el in arr)
  sortable.push([el, arr[el]])
sortable.sort(function(a, b) {return a[1] - b[1]})
//[["B", 60], ["C", 200], ["A", 300],
```

Comment: Based on the first comments.. this is what exactly i'm thinking of

Answer (score 0):

If you store your key-value pairs in the opposite order, with the number as the key and the letter as the property, then you will be able to get the order you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on what Patrick posted, you can create an index of the keys sorted by their values:

```
var obj = {A: 1, k:7, q:0, z:4};
var index = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
              return obj[a] - obj[b];
            });

// Keys sorted by value
console.log(index.join()); // q,A,z,k

// Get 2nd highest value
console.log(obj[index[1]]) // 1

// Get highest value
console.log(obj[index[index.length - 1]]) // 7
```

You could also create an object of value:key pairs, provided that `value.toString()` returns a unique value:

```
// Create a reversed object of value:key
var revObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(newObj, key){
               newObj[obj[key]] = key;
               return newObj;
             }, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(revObj)); // {"0":"q","1":"A","4":"z","7":"k"}
```

Note that in some browsers, the keys are sorted by numeric value, not the order they are added to *revObj* (or any other particular order).